# Convergence in measure theory context

Tags: measure-theory

I am studying for a test in measure theory. Please help with the following question:

Let 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} \ln^2(x)& 0<x \\ 0,& x\leq 0\end{cases}
\end{equation}
For every $n\geq 1$, let $f_n(x)=f(x-\frac{1}{n})$.

By using measure theory, please prove that:
$\lim_{(n\to\infty)} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx $.

Since $f_n$ is a decreasing sequence, not bounded and $f_n \geq f$ when $x-\frac{1}{n}>0$, I couldn't use any of the theorems I tried.

Comment: $f_1(x)=f(x-1)$ so e.g. $f_1(\frac12)=f(-\frac12)=0<f(\frac12)$. What makes you say that $f_n\geq f$?

Comment: I corrected the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

$$\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x-1/n) dx \\= \int_{-1/n}^{1-1/n} f(x) dx \\= \int_0^{1-1/n} f(x) dx \\= \int_0^1 f(x) \chi_{[0,1-1/n]}(x) dx.$$

Now $\chi_{[0,1-1/n]}$ is *increasing* and $f$ is nonnegative, so $f_n$ is an increasing sequence of nonnegative functions. So you can use monotone convergence.